# How do I publish only one page to production after making changes on staging?

Tags: php, functions, pages, production

Is it possible to push only one view to production?  For example.  I made a change on view A a while back on staging and it's just been sitting in staging.

Later on, I'm asked to make a change on view B.  The catch is:  I don't want the changes on view A to be live in production yet.  I only want the changes in view B to be in production.  Is this possible?  (I'm using GoDaddy.com, if that matters).

I can't find anything online that pertains to my question.  I'd imagine something like this definitely exists.

Thanks for taking the time to read :D

Comment: Your question does not seems to be wordpress related but a more general dev/prod architecture

Comment: @AndreaSomovigo probably not :( sorry I'm kind of new around here.

Answer (score 2):

No, not unless you push the change manually.

More specifically, WordPress has no concept of production/preprod/etc or of pushing/pulling. These features are always implemented by hosts or custom software, and  are extensions of WP, not parts  of WP itself.

Otherwise, production and preprod etc are just 2 separate WP installations that just happen to be very similar and run similar code.

If you want to migrate changes in a post on preprod to production, you can do that manually. Open the post up on the target environment, and retrace your steps to redo the changes you wanted. You can open both side by side and compare, and copy/paste things. As mentioned before, WP has no concept of push or pull content, there is no built in tool for what you seek.

Alternatively your host may  have a solution for this in their staging/preprod/production feature, but most do not. You would need to ask your host about that. There may also be plugins that assist in this out there. I don't know of any, and plugin recommendations aren't in the scope of this stack anyway

Comment: ah ok, how would I push the change manually?  are there any docs out there I can go off of?

Comment: Usually via copy paste, or duplicating the steps you took on the other environment, there's no special WordPress tool or trick, afterall WordPress has no concept of "push". Open it up on both environments and copy it over manually, comparing inputs/checkboxes/content areas

Comment: yeah I was just thinking that... thanks!